# Make specific href id as set default page

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have a menu bar with 4 id links as shown below. I want the 3rd link to be the default home page when the user visits the site (FAQ) not the 1st as it is now. How can this be done?

```
 <div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div><a class="0 move" href="#home">Home</a></div>
        <div><a class="2 move" href="#affiliates">Affiliates</a></div>
        <div><a class="3 move" href="#faq">FAQ</a></div>            
        <div><a class="4 move" href="#signup">Sign Up</a></div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: I see, i thought it was as simple as just adding a class "active" or something along those lines

Comment: adding a class changes only the style of the menu

Comment: Do you have a single page?

Comment: yeah its one page, exactly. Right now it automatically shows "home" when you visit the site, I want it to show "FAQ" instead. But without changing the order in the HTML list. Therefore FAQ would still stay 3rd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current `hash` and test if it's empty, so you update the `hash` with **javascript**. It'll scroll automatically to `#faq` area

```
var url = document.URL, 
    index = url.indexOf("#"),
    hash = index != -1 ? url.substring(index+1) : "";

if(hash === ""){
    location.hash = "#faq";
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02e13hqo/) and a [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02e13hqo/3/)